# Is there a way to update an ngModel from within the component?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, typescript

I'm currently working on an Angular project and my files originally looked as follows:

dog.ts:

```
export interface Dog {
   name: string;
   age: number;
   breed: string;
}
```

dog.component.ts:

```
import { Dog } from '../dog';

@Component({
//setup stuff
})

export class DogComponent implements OnInit {
   dog: Dog = {
      name: "",
      age: 0,
      breed: ""
   };

constructor() {}

method(dog: Dog): void {
   //methods with headers similar to above that use the passed dog object
}
```

dog.component.html:

```
<div class="input">
   <div>
      <label for="name">Name: </label>
      <input id="name" [(ngModel)]="dog.name" placeholder="name">
   </div>
   <div>
      <label for="age">Age: </label>
      <input id="age" [(ngModel)]="dog.age" placeholder=0>
   </div>
   <div>
      <label for="breed">Breed: </label>
      <input id="breed" [(ngModel)]="dog.breed" placeholder="breed">
   </div>
</div>

<button class="method" (click)="method(dog)">
   Use Method
</button>

<!--more buttons calling various functions -->
```

However, I'm now getting rid of the input fields in my .html file and replacing them with a singular input for a different model, as follows:

dog.component.html:

```
<div class="input">
   <div>
      <label for="place">Name: </label>
      <input id="place" [(ngModel)]="ranking.place" placeholder="place">
   </div>
</div>

<!-- Same buttons as before -->
```

I then created a service that, given a ranking object, will make a GET http request and return a dog object. So I now want to make a method in my dog.component.ts file that will update the dog model when given a ranking. So something like this:

dog.component.ts:

```
import { Dog } from '../dog';
import { Ranking } from '../ranking';

@Component({
//setup stuff
})

export class DogComponent implements OnInit {
   dog: Dog = {
      name: "",
      age: 0,
      breed: ""
   };

   ranking: Ranking = {
      place: 0,
   };

constructor() {}

updateDogComponenet(ranking: Ranking): void {
   //FILL IN THIS METHOD
   //insert a call to serviceFunction that takes a ranking and returns a dog
   //update the ngModel dog object so that it can be used in other functions
}

method(dog: Dog): void {
   //methods with headers similar to above that use the passed dog object
}
```

I apologize for all of the code, but if anyone has any ideas, that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the purpose of your application, but a way of sorting things out is to find the logical path.

You must have a system for ranking the dogs, maybe you can add a "points" or "score" property to the Dog class.

```
export class Dog {
   name: string;
   age: number;
   breed: string;
   score: number;
}
```

Then depending on the score, you can sort the dogs in descending order (the dog with the most number of points will be the first).

In that case you won't need the Ranking class, you can use the Array of Dog objects that you have and sort the array by the score attribute, then display it in the HTML.

I'm not sure if this will help you because I don't have the full context of your application, but I gave you an idea of how I would handle the problem.

Comment: I considered this approach, but if I have a method that makes an HTTP call to a database with the ranking/score as its parameter and returned a dog object with all of the fields filled in, I'm not sure how I would be able to use that completed dog object in other methods then. I could call that method in every other method, but that seems like it would be a lot of excess GET calls then. I guess my problem is I'm just not sure how to store those other fields then.

Comment: Wait, I just figured out I can use the this. keyword to update my dog object. Solved! I'll give you the check for trying to help with my mess of a question.